# Why no public constructor for Optional in java?

Tags: java, constructor, java-8, option-type

Why does `Optional` have methods like `of()` and `ofNullable()` instead of a public constructor?

Comment: Because empty is a singleton for memory efficiency.

Comment: Because how an `Optional` is created is an implementation detail

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From Joshua Bloch effective Java, Chapter 2. Creating and Destroying
Objects, 1 Item:

> Consider static factory methods instead of constructors

Why?

> One advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors,
>   they have names.

With static factory methods we can specify some instantiation behavior in the method definition. This makes the API easier to use and we prevent clients from calling wrong constructors.

For instance here: In [`Optional.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) -> we allow null value be passed to instantiate the [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), in [`Optional.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of-T-) null value is not allowed and throw exception. We could not use the constructor here.

```
private Optional(T value) {
    this.value = Objects.requireNonNull(value); //this throws NullPointerException
}
public static <T> Optional<T> of(T value) {
        return new Optional<>(value);
}
public static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(T value) {
        return value == null ? empty() : of(value);
}
```

Another advantage (already mentioned):

> A second advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike
>   constructors, they are not required to create a new object each time
>   they’re invoked.

In Optional, the empty value is instantiated just once, and then stored in the static field, this value is reused always when the program needs an empty value.

```
private static final Optional<?> EMPTY = new Optional<>(); //instantiate value when program starts

public static<T> Optional<T> empty() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Optional<T> t = (Optional<T>) EMPTY; //return stored value when requested
    return t;
}
```

Comment: And not to forget: the names `of` and `ofNullable` do not only document the different semantics of theses two factories, they also make them even possible, as we have two methods with identical type signatures, hence need different names to declare them in the same class. Since constructors don't have names, it is impossible to declare two of them with identical argument types.

Comment: Of course he means that on the *public* API. I mean, obviously you need to have constructors eventually, it can't just be an endless chain of factory methods... or can it?!

Answer (score 21):

The reason is actually quite simple: an empty optional is a static constant to be more memory efficient. If a constructor were used, it would have to create a new instance every time for a common case.

```
public static<T> Optional<T> empty() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Optional<T> t = (Optional<T>) EMPTY;
    return t;
}

public static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(T value) {
    return value == null ? empty() : of(value);
}
```

Comment: Having a public constructor doesn't preclude having a static method that returns a singleton instance.

Comment: I have not said that would be the case, I only answered the question.

Comment: "If a constructor were used, it would have to create a new instance every time for a common case." - the way this is worded to me implies that you would have to use the constructor rather than use the factory method. Perhaps you could reword it to be clear that having a public constructor would mean people would be more likely to create duplicate empty instances?

Answer (score 10):

Optional is a [Value-based Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) without any constructors

> do not have accessible constructors, but are instead instantiated through factory methods which **make no committment as to the identity of returned instances**

Comment: The OP knows that. He's asking why that is.

Comment: @JBNizet Do you think the OP actually asked: why value-based classes have no accessible constructors?

Comment: No. I think he asked why the designers of Optional chose not to add a public constructor to Optional. Answering that Optional is a value class and thus doesn't have a public constructor doesn't answer the question, IMHO.

Comment: @JBNizet: I think it does answer the question technically, but opens other questions: "What is a value class", and "What are the advantages of a value class".  This answer would be better if it also contained those bigs of information.

Answer (score 9):

Because factory methods should be favored over public constructors when the possible instantiation cases are known.
It makes the API easier to use for client classes.
Besides factory methods allow to decide whether an instance should be created at each invocation.
In the case of [`Optional.empty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--) it makes sense to cache the value as that is immutable.